# Is the use of globals in Javascript encouraged?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Most of my experience is in C++, and, for one reason or another, I am under the impression that global variables are bad practice. I am taking a course that discusses ES6, and the lesson uses the following program to demonstrate default arguments:

```
let lineNumber = 1;

function printComment( comment, line = lineNumber++ ) {
  console.log( line, comment );
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
  printComment('I should be lineNumber ' + i);
```

What is the difference between passing lineNumber as an argument and iterating a global variable, and would you ever consider passing lineNumber as an argument and iterating it locally (in the for loop)? If so, when is one approach better practice than the other? I realize that I may be thinking in terms of C++ and not in terms of ES6, so even a basic explanation helps shift my mindset.

Comment: Illustrations like this in tutorials should not be interpreted as endorsement of real-world programming practices. It's just to show you how default parameter values work. The exact same code would work if nested inside an enclosing function, rendering the question of global variables moot.

Comment: You're right. Poor phrasing on my part. The question still stands, however. In my experience, you always pass a variable like `lineNumber` as an argument and iterate after the function has completed. What makes ES6 different, and why is it useful?

Comment: Global variables are evil. Global constants are fine. What's the difference? Mutability. Don't mutate stuff you don't own. Besides, being garbage collected means that half the need for globals in c go away: i.e. global buffers to avoid dynamic allocations. You can pass around data structures without worrying about who has to call free.

Comment: In JavaScript, all that code could be in the context of an enclosing function. The concept "global" is relative. Look at that code again and try to understand the role of that `lineNumber` variable in the implementation of the example function. Passing it as a parameter really would not make any sense.